# Almost sure convergence with Borel–Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d.; $\mathbb{E} [X_i] = 0$; $\mathbb{E} [e^{t X_i}] \le e^\frac{t^2}{2}$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. It can be shown, by Markov's inequality, that $\mathbb{P} \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \ge s \right] \le e^{-\frac{s^2}{2n}}$, where $t = \frac{s}{n}$.

From there, the proof argues, with $s := qn, q >0$, that $\mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \left| \sum_{i = 1} X_i \right| \ge q \right] = \mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \right] + \mathbb{P} \left[ -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \right] \le 2 e^{-\frac{n q^2}{2}}$, to then sandwich the former probability with Borel–Cantelli.

I understand that $\{ \frac{1}{n} \left| \sum_{i = 1} X_i \right| \ge q \} = \{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \} \cup \{ -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \}$ is a disjoint union and that $\mathbb{P} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \right] \le e^{-\frac{n q^2}{2}}$. How can I argue, though, that also $\mathbb{P} \left[ -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1} X_i \ge q \right] \le e^{-\frac{n q^2}{2}}$ (which the proof seems to do)?

Comment: You said: "then sandwich the former probability with Borel-Cantelli." Did you perhaps mean Markov's inequality instead? And if so, what is the obstruction to applying that inequality to the other term?

Comment: Hi Aaron -- let $A_{n, q} := \{ \frac{1}{n} | \sum_{i = 1}^n| \}$. With $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P} [A_{n, q}] \le 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (e^{-\frac{q^2}{2}})^n = \frac{2}{1 - e^{-\frac{q^2}{2}}} < \infty$, Borell–Cantelli implies that $\mathbb{P} [A_{n, q} \, \text{occurs for infinitely many} \, n] = 0$. This can be used to show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I believe that this is not necessary for the step where I'm stuck, though. I think my problem boils down to showing that $\mathbb{P} [|X| \ge q] = \mathbb{P} [X \ge q] + \mathbb{P} [-X \ge q] \le 2 e^{-\frac{s^2}{q}}$ when $\mathbb{P} [X \ge q] \le e^{-\frac{s^2}{q}}$. I just wanted to be sure to provide all relevant information.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was being too hasty in my original reply. Although, it looks like there are some terms missing in your first reply -- could you clarify your definition of $A_{n, q}$?

Comment: Actually, $A_{n, q} := \{ \frac{1}{n} |\sum_{i = 1}^n| \ge q \}$. I'm sorry I forgot to include $\ge q$ in my first reply.

Comment: Ah! Okay, my misunderstanding was that I interpreted your use of "the former" to mean $\mathbb P[\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq q]$, when indeed you intended $\mathbb P[\frac 1 n |\sum_{i=1}^n X_i | \geq q]$. @Kavi has the right idea.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! Kavi's comment helped indeed. It seems that my problem was the exponential version of Chebyshev's inequality rather than the Borel–Cantelli lemma. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple! You already know that $P[\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \geq q] \leq e^{-nq^{2}} /2$ whenever $\{X_i\}$ is i.i.d with mean 0 and $Ee^{tX_i} \leq e^{t^{2}/2}$ for all real $t$. Just change $\{X_i\}$ to $\{-X_i\}$ in this and verify that the hypothesis is still satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, Kavi. The point where I got stuck seems to be the exponential version of Chebyshev's inequality: $\mathbb{P} [X \ge \varepsilon] \le \frac{\mathbb{E} [e^{tX}]}{e^{t \varepsilon}}$, $t \ge 0$. I understand that this inequality holds for all real-valued random variables (not just non-negative random variables), which allows me to apply it to $\{ -X_i \}$ as much as to $\{ X_i \}$.